# Typescript magic properties

Tags: typescript

I'm starting working with Typescript and stuck a bit. Is it possible to allow TypeScript classes use properties added on runtime?
I'm using something like this:

```
interface IObject {
   [key: string]: any;
}

class A {
    private extends: IObject = {};


    constructor() {
        return new Proxy(this, {
            get: (target: any, name: string) => (name in this.extends) ? this.extends[name] : target[name],
        })
    }

    public extend(key: any, argument: object): A {
       this.extends = Object.assign(this.extends, {
           [key]: argument
       });

       return this;
   }
}
```

So this class is something like extendable context in my application.
I can add any properties here in runtime like `aInstance.extend('property', {a: 1})` and use them like this `aInstance.property`. In pure JS it will return `{a: 1}` as expected, but TypeScript throws an error (*Property 'property' does not exist on type 'A'.*) while doing this. So is there any workaround to avoid this? I know I could use `// @ts-ignore`, but I don't want to use this because it will be much harder to maintain the code.

Will be appreciate for any advice here. Thank you :)

Answer (score 1):

I don't think it is possible to do exactly what you want and keep things typesafe. One option would be to do something like this:

```
class A {
    private extends: Record<string, any> = {};

    constructor() {
        return new Proxy(this, {
            get: (target: any, name: string) => (name in this.extends) ? this.extends[name] : target[name],
        })
    }

    public extend<T extends object>(obj: T): A & T {
       this.extends = Object.assign(this.extends, obj);

       // necessary evil, but safe because we know we are returning A & T due to the proxy
       return this as any;
   }
}

let aInstance = new A()
let extended = aInstance.extend({"test": "foo"})

console.log(extended.test)
```

Basically the extend method is now returning a type that is the union of A and T. The drawback is that only the return value of the extend function will be typed as having the extra property.

I'd consider why you need to extend the type at runtime in the first place?

If you know the property names ahead of time, then just add them to the class. Otherwise it sounds like a Map might be a better fit for the job.

Comment: I'm working on chat bot framework for social network. Currently it supports middleware and they can modify current context on the way they need. I don't actually know property names, they could be added at runtime as I said. But in your example I'm still confused. Will this work if i'll extend class with more than one property?

Comment: Well it works in my project thanks.
Is there are any way to declare something like my `IObject` to declare class properties?

Comment: How do you mean? Class properties should ideally be declared directly on the class. If you're wanting an example of how composable context can be typed you might want to checkout the typings for koa https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/master/types/koa/index.d.ts

Answer (score 0):

```
// Some mocking to be able to run and test your code:


type IObject = {};

class Proxy{
    constructor(obj:any, c:{get:(target:any, name:string) => any}) {

    }
}

class A {
    private extends: IObject = {};

    // recommend to implement this not in the constructor
    // otherwise I recommend to define A as Class A extends Proxy{}
    getProxy() {
        return new Proxy(this, {
            get: (target: any, name: string) => (name in this.extends) ? this.extends[name] : target[name],
        })
    }

    // not sure what you wanted to achieve with Proxy Class, but the following
    // Object.defineProperty might answer your issue
    public extend(key: any, argument: object): A {
        // if you want to access your property like :
        // aInstance.property
        Object.defineProperty(A.prototype, key, {
            get: function () {
                return argument;
            },
            set: function (value) {
                this[key] = value;
            },
            enumerable: true,
            configurable: true
        });

        // other wise property will be available at 
        // aInstance.extends.property
        this.extends = {...this.extends, ...{
            [key]: argument
        }};

        return this;
    }
}

const aInstance: A = new A();


aInstance.extend('property', { a: 1 });

// (aInstance as any) is needed to avoid lint checking
console.log(aInstance, (aInstance as any).property);

// will print
// A { extends: { property: { a: 1 } } } { a: 1 }
```

**edit**

```
console.log(aInstance['property']); // will also works
```

Comment: Casting to any isn't really any better than using ts-ignore in my opinion. Either way you are by-passing the type system.

Comment: console.log(aInstance, aInstance['property']); also works, I think he wants to add dynamically properties to a Class A which cant be aware of what prop will have. I don't see other chances at the moment.

Comment: `aInstance["property"]` is still not typesafe - `Element implicitly has an 'any' type because expression of type '"property"' can't be used to index type 'A'.
  Property 'property' does not exist on type 'A'.(7053)`. I've posted a solution using union types, but I think that the best solution is probably not to dynamically add properties to the class in the first place.

Comment: Nice alternative but you’re just moving the not typesafe thing to another instance.. of type any

Comment: I'm not though - consumers of the class do not see an `any` type, they see `A & T` which means that you can access the extended property with type safety.